# Value of one variable is automatically assigned to second one

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am learning web-scraping but while formatting the scraped data I came across a problem that my two variables i.e. first_line and second_line are both showing same value and that value is of second_line.

Inside the else  when I tried printing out first_line then I got expected result but outside if and else first_line is showing copied value from second_line

```
while current_page < 201:
    print(current_page)
    url = base_url + loc + "&start=" + str(current_page)
    yelp_r = requests.get(url)
    yelp_soup = BeautifulSoup(yelp_r.text, 'html.parser')
    file_path = 'yelp-{loc}-2.txt'.format(loc=loc)
    with open(file_path, "a") as textfile:
        business = yelp_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'biz-listing-large'})
        for biz in business:
            title = biz.findAll('a', {'class':'biz-name'})[0].text
            print(title)
            second_line = ""
            first_line = ""
            try:
                address = biz.findAll('address')[0].contents
                for item in address:
                    if "br" in str(item):
                        second_line = second_line + item.getText()
                    else:
                        first_line = item.strip(" \n\t\r")              
                        print(first_line)
                print(first_line)
                print(second_line)
            except:
                pass
            print('\n')     
            try:
                phone = biz.findAll('span',{'class':'biz-phone'})[0].text
            except:
                phone = None
            print(phone)
            page_line = "{title}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{phone}".format(
                title=title,
                address_1=first_line,
                address_2=second_line,
                phone=phone
                )
            textfile.write(page_line)
    current_page += 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) on a node, it gives you the full text. You can then split on newline to get your first and second line:

```
first_line, second_line = biz.findAll('address')[0].get_text().split('\n')
```

But since you just print `f'{first_line}\n{second_line}'`, why do you need them separate at all?

Comment: Yes I could have done this but first_line have trailing spaces which I need to remove using strip

Comment: But  I am really not getting why value of second_line is being copied to the first_line

Comment: Your original code is wrong because `<br>` has no textual content. So `item.getText()` is just returning everything. That's the root cause, but the true cause is you're trying to do something yourself that's already been implemented. `get_text()` is complicated. Take advantage of the API that already works (and understands HTML very deeply)!